# Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

i have this problem in my service: Type Observable 'Object' is not assignable to type Observable 'Product. Have you any idea how to solve it?
this is my class

```
export class Product{
  public id:number;
  public price:number;
}
```

My ts:

```
onSaveProduct(data: any) {
    this.catService.saveResource(this.catService.host+"/produits",data)
      .subscribe(res=>{
        this.currentProduct=res
      },err=>{
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

My service:

```
public saveResource(url,data):Observable<Product>{
    return this.httpClient.post(url,data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the Observable in the post call itself

```
public saveResource(url,data):Observable<Product>{
    return this.httpClient.post<Product>(url,data);
}
```

Comment: Thanx Stoobish, your answer resolved my problem.